# Pandas. Объединение с условием

Tags: python, pandas

Есть два датафрейма. Объединяю их по двум нужным столбцам, в которых есть одинаковые значения. Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы при объединении последний столбец "ОПТ" выводил данные только в том случае, если наличие Не равно нулю или не пустое. Или по другому: Если наличие ноль или пустое значение, то цена, в столбце "ОПТ" оставалась пустой ячейкой.
Так же после преобразования необходимо удалить стобцы "Артикул" и "Наличие".

Спасибо. Всем здоровья.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pandas as pd
goods = pd.DataFrame({'Модель': ['Гитара', 'Пианино', 'Барабан', 'Скрипка', 'Укулеле'], 'Attrade': ['A114980', 'A222', 'A150136', 'A050344', 'A7444']})
suppliers = pd.DataFrame({'Поставщик': ['Attrade', 'Attrade', 'Attrade','Attrade', 'Attrade', 'Attrade', 'Attrade'], 'Артикул': ['A114980', 'A222', 'A333', 'A7444', 'A150136', '666', 'A050344'], 'Наличие': ['>5', '0', '0', '0', 'в наличии', '0', '2'], 'ОПТ': ['13200', '78000', '8600', '12500', '6500', '4610', '6540']})
merged = pd.merge(goods, suppliers, left_on = 'Attrade', right_on = 'Артикул', how = 'left')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял:

```py
merged.loc[(merged['Наличие'] == '0')|(merged['Наличие'] == ''), 'ОПТ'] = pd.NA
merged = merged.drop(columns=['Артикул', 'Наличие'])
merged
```

Вывод:

```
    Модель  Attrade Поставщик ОПТ
0   Гитара  A114980 Attrade   13200
1   Пианино A222    Attrade   <NA>
2   Барабан A150136 Attrade   6500
3   Скрипка A050344 Attrade   6540
4   Укулеле A7444   Attrade   <NA>
```

По крайней мере методику я вам показал, детали можете сами подрихтовать.

Comment: Да, супер! То, что нужно. Огромное спасибо.

Comment: @Дмитрий вы, кстати, возьмите за правило принимать ответ на ваш вопрос, если он вам помог. ответ так же можно "плюсануть".

Comment: @CrazyElf да, спасибо за совет. Это мои первые шаги на этом сайте. Посмотрел туториал. Разобрался. Поставил галочку.